# How to remove the embedded Youtube video Title in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade, embedded-video

I want to remove the title from an embedded video in my Laravel Blade template, marked with orange color in the picture. That video may be a youtube video or any video from other websites.

[image: embedded video]

**Here is my code**

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="width:300px;height: 100px; margin:0px 50px 30px 0px;">
   {!! Embed::make($data->links)->parseUrl()->getIframe() !!}
</div>
```

`showinfo=0` is not help here cause may be it can't a youtube video.

Is there a way to add any code inside `{!! Embed::make($data->links)->parseUrl()->getIframe() !!}`  or any solution ?

Comment: @arun kumar....it gives error `Call to a member function setAttribute() on string`.

Comment: stil same error... here is my code `$embed = Embed::make($data->links)->parseUrl()->getIframe(); $embed->setAttribute(['showinfo' => 0]);`

Comment: error `Object of class Cohensive\Embed\Embed could not be converted to string`
after using`Embed::make($data->links)->parseUrl()->setAttribute(['showinfo' => 0]);`

Comment: i will try the code and get back to u

Comment: okay @arunkumar